# How can I test to see if my touchpad is supports more than 2 finger gestures?

Tags: 11.04, multi-touch

I'd like to use some of the Unity multitouch features. I know my touchpad supports 2 finger gestures since it scrolls when I 2 finger drag on the touchpad.

How can I test to see if my touchpad supports three and four finger gestures? All the hardware documentation just mentions that the touchpad is multitouch and doesn't specify how many fingers it support. It's a Thinkpad X120e and this is what dmesg says:

```
[   14.821482] Synaptics Touchpad, model: 1, fw: 7.5, id: 0x1e0b1, caps: 0xd000b3/0x340000/0xa0400
[   14.821498] serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio4/input0
[   14.864676] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input7
```

Comment: For a simpler and more accurate solution - try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/306412/how-can-i-setup-my-touchpad-multi-finger-tapping-functionality (see the answer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As an update to **[htorque's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/33589/112901)**, you must now use `geis-tools` instead of `utouch-geis-tools` (> 12.04). So run the following set of commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geis-tools
geisview
```

In the new window, go under **`Device`**`<device_id>`**`Added:`**`<device_name>` (Probably the last option) and check `device touches: <finger_number>`. finger_number will tell you the number of multi-touch fingers your touchpad supports.

Comment: In 13.04, this solution doesnt work. For a easier and more accurate solution try this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/306412/how-can-i-setup-my-touchpad-multi-finger-tapping-functionality

Comment: Works like a charm in 64-bits 14.04

Answer (score 7):

You can install `utouch-geis-tools` and then run `geistest`, which shows you information about the device and gestures, e.g.:

```
Device 10 added
    attr "device name" = "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    attr "device id" = 10
    attr "direct touch" = false
    attr "independent touch" = false
    attr "device touches" = 4
    ....
```

where the last attribute is defined as the number of simultaneous touches the devices claims to be able to recognize.

However, uTouch doesn't seem to recognize more than two fingers on my system (ThinkPad T510), because `geistest` always shows

```
    ...
    attr "gesture name" = "Tap,touch=2"
    ...
```

when doing three or four finger taps, but I don't know if that's a hardware or software limitation (I just made this a [bug report](//bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/utouch/+bug/751030)).

Comment: I have the same problem, looks like I'll have to file a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Touchegg from http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/ lets you use multitouch gestures

If it works correctly (it doesn't on my end) it should let you test how many fingers you can use.

(by the way, if you just want to know if the touchpad supports multitouch, why don't you just check the specs?)

Comment: touchegg looks nice but I accepted the other answer since the tool is already in the archive. Still +1, looks like a nice program!