# How can I setup my touchpad multi-finger tapping functionality?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I'm trying to setup my multi-finger tap in the following way:

- Single finger - Left click
- **Two fingers - Middle click**
- **Three fingers - Right click**

What I currently have is:

- Single finger - Left click
- **Two fingers - Right click**
- **Three fingers - none**

I've looked up several questions here on Ask Ubuntu, as well as the Ubuntu wiki on the subject (plus some general Google searching), but couldn't find anything to help me out. I know of `xinput`, but I don't know what to change there and how.

If anyone is able to point me to the right direction, I'd be grateful and award him with 25 shiny rep points, a large green tick mark, and some cookies.

Comment: You may have a look @ this link   

http://askubuntu.com/a/155725/44518

Comment: @karan: How does this relate to my problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done using `synclient`.

To do this per-session (and to test that it's working correctly on your system), type into a terminal the following commands:

```
synclient "TapButton2"=2
synclient "TapButton3"=3
```

The option `TapButtonx` means "A tap with x fingers, not in a corner", while the numbers 1, 2 and 3 after correspond to left, middle and right click respectively.

To make these changes permanent, navigate to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. `ls` to find the file with "synaptics.conf" in the name (in my case, `50-synaptics.conf`). Then, `sudo gedit 50-synaptics.conf`, and add the following lines into the end of the first InputClass section:

```
Option "TapButton2" "2"
Option "TapButton3" "3"
```

Then restart your machine, and you should be good to go.

If editing the `50-synaptics.conf` file doesn't work, do the following:
open `dconf-editor` and navigate to `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse`. Uncheck the box marked "active" and restart again. This will allow the synaptics settings to take precedence.

Comment: This is looking good. I have mutliple instances of `Section "InputClass"`, which do I edit?

Comment: At the end of the first section is where I have my settings. Oddly, adding more doesn't seem to be working properly for me at the moment (13.04)... which is strange as I definitely have some custom ones added. I'll let you know if I figure out why, but in theory this should work.

Comment: Answer has been edited, should all be working as desired now. At least, this method fixed it for me again! =)

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it and get back to you (might be a short while before I can actually restart my computer and test it) Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: **[Thank you, it works. Have this](http://imgur.com/gallery/trCIY)**.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what we need to do:

1. First we gather the ID for the trackpad/mouse pad.

   ```
   $ xinput --list  
   Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
   ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]    
   **⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]  **
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]    
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
   ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
   ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
   ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
   ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
   ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ```
2. Now the highlighted one is our device with ID in my case **11**
3. List out the properties and hence configuring the one against the ID

   ```
   $ xinput --list-props 11  
   Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':  
   Device Enabled (132):   1  
   Coordinate Transformation Matrix (134): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,   1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000  
   Device Accel Profile (253): 1  
   Device Accel Constant Deceleration (254):   2.500000  
   Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (255):   1.000000  
   Device Accel Velocity Scaling (256):    12.500000  
   Synaptics Edges (276):  1769, 5431, 1653, 4671  
   Synaptics Finger (277): 25, 30, 256  
   Synaptics Tap Time (278):   180  
   Synaptics Tap Move (279):   242  
   Synaptics Tap Durations (280):  180, 180, 100  
   Synaptics ClickPad (281):   0  
   Synaptics Tap FastTap (282):    0  
   Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (283):  75  
   Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (284):    282  
   Synaptics Two-Finger Width (285):   7  
   Synaptics Scrolling Distance (286): 110, 110  
   Synaptics Edge Scrolling (287): 1, 0, 0  
   Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (288):   0, 0  
   Synaptics Move Speed (289): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.036265, 40.000000  
   Synaptics Edge Motion Pressure (290):   30, 160  
   Synaptics Edge Motion Speed (291):  1, 441  
   Synaptics Edge Motion Always (292): 0  
   Synaptics Off (293):    0  
   Synaptics Locked Drags (294):   0  
   Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (295):   5000  
   Synaptics Tap Action (296): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0  
   Synaptics Click Action (297):   1, 1, 0  
   Synaptics Circular Scrolling (298): 0  
   Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (299):    0.100000  
   Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (300): 0  
   Synaptics Circular Pad (301):   0  
   Synaptics Palm Detection (302): 0  
   Synaptics Palm Dimensions (303):    10, 200  
   Synaptics Coasting Speed (304): 20.000000, 50.000000  
   Synaptics Pressure Motion (305):        ... of unknown type CARDINAL  

   Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (306): 1.000000, 1.000000  
   Synaptics Resolution Detect (307):  1  
   Synaptics Grab Event Device (308):  1  
   Synaptics Gestures (309):   1  
   Synaptics Capabilities (310):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  
   Synaptics Pad Resolution (311): 85, 45  
   Synaptics Area (312):   0, 0, 0, 0  
   Synaptics Noise Cancellation (313): 8, 8  
   Device Product ID (249):    2, 7  
   Device Node (250):  "/dev/input/event8"
   ```
4. Now find the point, in this case its 285, 288.  Using the command you may configure the same on your touch pad.

   ```
   $xinput set-int-prop <properties>
   ```
5. Hope this helps