# Touchpad emulate right click and hold with 3 fingers

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I have a Firefox plug-in called "All-in-One Gestures" I have a new Lenovo laptop with ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad and no mouse.

What I would like to achieve is the following: when I move three fingers over the touchpad, I would like to emulate mouse movement with right click pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing touchegg: https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/Downloads?tm=2

It's not maintained, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Good options, though i'm already tried it. My problem with touchegg was that in order to propely operate i had to disable vertical scrolling and use touchegg for that as well, but that way vertical scrolling is a gesture and i had some issue with the sensitivity.
I even tried to set up ginn which seems more promising for me but no luck with it yet.

Comment: :) ok will suggest something else... Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @bonyiii - Honestly, Ubuntu doesn't have the best touchpad options while F20 KDE is the best. http://www.fclose.com/wp/files/2012/06/kde-tapping-touchpad-left-click.png wish we had something with ubuntu

Comment: This still works as of Ubuntu 18.10. `touchegg` is available in the repos now, so installing is simply `sudo apt install touchegg`. The code is [here](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg), and there has been some work after 2014.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the Synaptics touchpad from the software centre. It give you a lot of options graphically for configuring your touchpad.

Also you could check this out:
[How can I setup my touchpad multi-finger tapping functionality?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306412/how-can-i-setup-my-touchpad-multi-finger-tapping-functionality)

and the oficial Synaptics documentation:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'm using kde and there is an excellent graphical tool ```/usr/bin/kcmshell4 kcm_touchpad``` but that is not supporting this kind of so called advanced scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Touchpad driver:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then reboot.

Comment: What will it be good for?

Comment: @bonyiii sorry i couldnt get

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't specific enough. How will the command you mentioned help me to set up holding the right click emulation with touchpad?